# Custom Toggle Control "Checked" Property Does Not Save (Or Restore) With My.Settings()

Tags: vb.net, winforms, custom-controls, c#-to-vb.net

I added a custom control to my project, which is a [toggle switch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7Iv6xfjnuw&ab_channel=RJCodeAdvanceEN) that inherits the functionality of a checkbox. The problem I am facing is when I try to create an Application Setting to bind the control to, it does not save (or restore, I don't really know which) the Checked: property. **To be more clear, no exception is thrown. The toggle works as designed, however it does not save the state of whether it was checked or not when relaunching the program. It just defaults back to its assigned state that was set in the designer. It's just not saving the fact that it was checked or unchecked when closing or relaunching the program.** The My.Settings() code is fine, I've tested it with a checkbox and it saved and restored correctly. The problem lies in the Toggle.vb Class file I'd assume. Here is the source:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Namespace CustomControls.RJControls

    Public Class RJToggleButton
        Inherits CheckBox
        'Fields
        Private onBackColorField As Color = Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 128)
        Private onToggleColorField As Color = Color.White
        Private offBackColorField As Color = Color.Black
        Private offToggleColorField As Color = Color.White
        Private solidStyleField As Boolean = True

        'Properties
        <Category("RJ Code Advance")>
        Public Property OnBackColor As Color
            Get
                Return onBackColorField
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Color)
                onBackColorField = value
                Me.Invalidate()
            End Set
        End Property

        <Category("RJ Code Advance")>
        Public Property OnToggleColor As Color
            Get
                Return onToggleColorField
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Color)
                onToggleColorField = value
                Me.Invalidate()
            End Set
        End Property

        <Category("RJ Code Advance")>
        Public Property OffBackColor As Color
            Get
                Return offBackColorField
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Color)
                offBackColorField = value
                Me.Invalidate()
            End Set
        End Property

        <Category("RJ Code Advance")>
        Public Property OffToggleColor As Color
            Get
                Return offToggleColorField
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Color)
                offToggleColorField = value
                Me.Invalidate()
            End Set
        End Property

        <Browsable(False)>
        Public Overrides Property Text As String
            Get
                Return MyBase.Text
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
            End Set
        End Property

        <Category("RJ Code Advance")>
        <DefaultValue(True)>
        Public Property SolidStyle As Boolean
            Get
                Return solidStyleField
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
                solidStyleField = value
                Me.Invalidate()
            End Set
        End Property

        'Constructor
        Public Sub New()
            Me.MinimumSize = New Size(45, 22)
        End Sub

        'Methods
        Private Function GetFigurePath() As GraphicsPath
            Dim arcSize As Integer = Me.Height - 1
            Dim leftArc As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, arcSize, arcSize)
            Dim rightArc As Rectangle = New Rectangle(Me.Width - arcSize - 2, 0, arcSize, arcSize)
            Dim path As GraphicsPath = New GraphicsPath()
            path.StartFigure()
            path.AddArc(leftArc, 90, 180)
            path.AddArc(rightArc, 270, 180)
            path.CloseFigure()
            Return path
        End Function

        Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal pevent As PaintEventArgs)
            Dim toggleSize As Integer = Me.Height - 5
            pevent.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
            pevent.Graphics.Clear(Me.Parent.BackColor)

            If Me.Checked Then 'ON
                'Draw the control surface
                If solidStyleField Then
                    pevent.Graphics.FillPath(New SolidBrush(onBackColorField), GetFigurePath())
                Else
                    pevent.Graphics.DrawPath(New Pen(onBackColorField, 2), GetFigurePath())
                End If
                'Draw the toggle
                pevent.Graphics.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(onToggleColorField), New Rectangle(Me.Width - Me.Height + 1, 2, toggleSize, toggleSize)) 'OFF
            Else
                'Draw the control surface
                If solidStyleField Then
                    pevent.Graphics.FillPath(New SolidBrush(offBackColorField), GetFigurePath())
                Else
                    pevent.Graphics.DrawPath(New Pen(offBackColorField, 2), GetFigurePath())
                End If
                'Draw the toggle
                pevent.Graphics.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(offToggleColorField), New Rectangle(2, 2, toggleSize, toggleSize))
            End If
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

The binding code:

```
Private Sub FormMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Toggle1.Checked = My.Settings.ToggleState

    End Sub

Private Sub Toggle1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Toggle1.CheckedChanged

        My.Settings.ToggleState = Toggle1.Checked
        My.Settings.Save()

    End Sub
```

My Settings:

Name: ToggleState, Type: Boolean, Scope: User, Value: True

Since I am barely a novice when it comes to coding, is there someway I can make the toggle function exactly as a checkbox, or allow it's state to be saved with My.Settings()? What am I missing to add that functionality to the toggle?

*Environment: VB, .NET 6.0, Visual Basic 2022*

Comment: It's not clear when / how you're binding the `Checked` Property to a Project Setting -- If you have an exception when the Project's Settings are created or modified, see: [Updating the Default Settings file in a WinForms .NET 5 Visual Basic app fails](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/6784) -- Marked as a .Net 5 issue, but it's also a regression issues in .Net 6 and .Net 7 -- Easily solved by removing the `System.Diagostics` section from the `App.config` file, delete `VB Net X App.dll.config` in `netX.0-windows` and rebuild.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear enough in my post. No exception is thrown, the application runs just fine. The problem is only that the checked state does not restore when I relaunch the program. The toggle switch still works, but the state of whether it was checked or unchecked reverts back to its assigned property in the designer.

Comment: You have to show how you're crating the binding between the Control's Property and the Project's Setting. Assuming your Setting is in the `User` scope. -- BTW, the Custom Control is leaking graphic resources. The SolidBrush and Pen need to be declared with `Using` statements, you cannot have something like `New SolidBrush()` or `New Pen()` in `FillPath()` and `DrawPath()`

Comment: I'm creating the binding by going to Properties -> Settings and creating a new setting as a Boolean type, with User scope. Since it inherits a checkbox, that should give it it's full functionality, no? As for it leaking resources, why do they need to be declared, if the toggle visually works as intended? Thank you for the helpful information.

Comment: Creating a Setting is not enough, you need to also bind the Setting to a Property of a Control. -- Leaking graphic resources is one of the most common issues in this platform. It cannot be left unchecked, since the graphic resources are very limited. The fact that the Control's functionality appears to be unhindered is just because of lack of profiling. At some point, the application will crash or some parts of it will fail to render properly (classic *black holes*). That it runs in Visual Studio (or in your machine, for a limited time) is not a factor. Production is a different thing.

Comment: For example, add a Setting in `User` scope named `TbState` and Type `Boolean`. In the Constructor of a Form, add `RjToggleButton1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", My.Settings, "TbState", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)`, assuming the name assigned to the Custom Control is `RjToggleButton1`. -- Fix the leaking.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thank you. I've also updated my post to include how and what I'm binding, if that helps, or if I'm doing it incorrectly.

Comment: I've actually found the solution. I was setting the the Setting Boolean value as True, and the Toggle in the Designer as True as well. When both values were set to the same Boolean output, it caused the toggle to not save its state when the form was closed or opened (still have no clue which) . I fixed it by changing the Setting Boolean to True, and the Designer Boolean for the Toggle Switch to False. Just a question, if you do have an answer, why did it cause this issue? I assumed the Setting Boolean was acting as the default checked state, overwriting the designer, but I guess not.

Comment: Thank you @Jimi I was also having a problem with `My.Settings`, your previous comment and link <https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/6784> (Updating the Default Settings file in a WinForms .NET 5 Visual Basic app fails.) helped fix my problem. VB.NET WPF NET6.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the new Application Setting, the type Boolean was assigned, and the Value assigned was True. In the form Designer, the Checked Property was also set to True. It seemed the Setting Value True or False would set the Toggle's default checked state. The Checked Value in the designer **had** to be set to false, in order to allow the New Setting to function properly with My.Settings().